# Error narrow conversion when used with auto

Tags: c++

Getting error in use of auto for the implicit conversion.

Capturing the return of `v.size()` using int variable is ok but auto complains.
Compiler error does inform it is because of narrowing conversion .But I would like to understand in terms memory how this happens and why auto is not allowing it do that whereas normal conversion is ok

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3 };

    auto  c = 'h';
    auto n2 = int{c};
    std::cout<<n2<<" "<<c;

    auto size = int{v.size()};
    std::cout<<size;

    int size_1 = v.size();
    std::cout<<size_1;

}
```

Error because of below line 
     auto size = int{v.size()};

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:11:27: error: narrowing
>   conversion of 'v.std::vector::size()' from
>   'std::vector::size_type {aka long unsigned int}' to 'int' inside
>   { } [-Wnarrowing]

When that line is commented it works perfectly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3 };

    auto  c = 'h';
    auto n2 = int{c};
    std::cout<<n2<<" "<<c;

    //auto size = int{v.size()};
    //std::cout<<size;

    int size_1 = v.size();
    std::cout<<size_1;

}
```

Output

```
104 h3
```

[DEMO LINK](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5cf02262f4b57c12)

Comment: What's so hard to understand? You are converting a `long unsigned int` to `int` - which may truncate it. That's *bad* and you should be glad your friendly compiler warns you about it.

Comment: "Capturing the return of v.size() using int variable is ok" - No, it is *not*. `size()` does *not* return `int`. There is conversion happening and the result may not be what you expect. Braced initialization (and the compiler warning) is saving you from making a mistake here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `auto`.  You will get the same warning if you use

```
int size = int{v.size()};
```

The issue here is `int{v.size()}` is using *braced initialization* to initialize a temporary `int`.  A narrowing conversion in *braced initialization* is what causes the diagnostic to be displayed.

---

Do note that

```
int size_1 = v.size();
```

Is also a narrowing conversion, it is just not one where the standard mandates that a warning/error be emitted.

Comment: @HariomSingh `c` is a `char` and it is mandated that `sizeof(int) >= sizeof(char)` so there is no narrowing.

Comment: Maybe add that without the braced initialization the truncation still happens - it's just silently accepted (which doesn't make it correct in all cases though).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Good idea.  Done.